# Am I having a power supply issue with my LED lights strips in series, or have I done somethine else wrong?

Tags: light, led-strip

I bought two LED light strips and connected them together end-to-end using a solderless snap connect. The strips are each 5 meters long, "LEDMO SMD 2835 White Non-waterproof LED Light Strip - DC12V 600LEDs 16.4 Ft 6000K 15Lm/LED High CRI80". Then at one end I connected a remote control reciever "LE® Mini Remote Controller for Single Color LED Strip Lights, RF Dimmer for 12 V DC LED Light Strips, 12A". To that I then connected a power supply adapter that is "12V, 5A Max, 60 Watt Max". It works great for a couple of weeks and then the lights just get dim. It is like they are stuck at half power. I replaced the power supply once and they were bright again for a week or two and then they get dim again. I wonder if I am burning out the power supply because I have something configured wrong?

Comment: Relate the power the strip needs to the power your brick can provide

Comment: The Amazon page for that LED strip says to power one strip with one 5A power supply.  You are running two of these strips from one supply.  You are probably drawing too much current from the power supply, and at some point it just gives up and can't handle the overload any more.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance in these areas, but how would I determine the correct power supply to use?

Comment: Unless there is an absolute need for connecting two strips together, it might be better idea to power and control them individually. Parallel currents sum up. So, if you connected two strips, you need (2 x 5A) = 10A power supply. May not be a perfect idea though, as the copper traces towards the end of power supply have to carry the full 10A current. In worse case, it could lead to a fire hazard.

Comment: yes, the strips are run along the top of my cabinets, connected to one power source and one remote control, so they need to be chained

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to choose a power supply that has the appropriate capacity to drive your LED strips.  Since your strips need 5A at 12V to operate, and you are intending to run two strips off of one power supply, you need a power supply that can supply at least 10A at 12V.

So, search for a 12V power supply that can supply *at least* 10A.  If you want it to last a while, find one that can supply at least 15A.

Comment: Should I be concerned with what Vasu mentioned that there could be a fire hazard with the copper traces catching fire?

Comment: If the strips are not designed to be daisy-chained, then it could be a problem.

Comment: They seem like they are designed for that, but how can one tell for sure?

Comment: Consult the documentation provided by the vendor or manufacturer.

Comment: Alternatively, if you can estimate the wire gauge of the leads contained within the strip, you can get a rough idea of how much DC current it can support by comparing against a chart like [this one](http://www.powerstream.com/Wire_Size.htm).

Answer (score 0):

- you need to calculate Watts by meter and watts total per strip.
- with total wattage, calculate total watts divided by voltage.
- result will be the supply amp rating.

for exeample:

- watt/m - Watts x meters - Total Watts /12V = Amps needed
- 5.76W/m = 28W/5m = 2,4A (make at least 2,50A to be safe, 3,0A is better)
- 14.4W/m = 72W/5m = 6,0A (make at least 6,25A to be safe, 6,5A is better)

Hope it helps.